# Is instance that created from my own AMI Free Tier eligibility?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created my own intance and made AMI from it. Then, I deleted the old instance and created the new one with the AMI.

Here's the problem. I have been tracking my billing. It hasn't been eligible to Free Tier. This December, I spent almost $11 for EC2. I've used only EC2, I checked others services already.

Note that my first created instance is Micro instance with Ubuntu 13.

Do you have any ideas what does it come from?

Comment: Turn on detail billing.  You are probably using bandwidth, IOPS, or storage in excess of the free tier allowance. The free micro instance allowance is an allowance of 750 instance hours per month and shouldn't change with the source AMI if the original AMI you based it on was free-tier eligible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about billing and pricing from a specific vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use a t1.micro instance otherwise you are not eligible for the free tier. Also make sure your EBS volume is < 30GB otherwise you will be charged.